# Pandoc adds extra paragraph breaks

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I use `pandoc` to convert Markdown to Latex. My problem is that `pandoc` adds extra paragraph breaks around begin/end environments.

Source:

```
**First** phrase in a paragraph.
\begin{multline*}
some long formulae
\end{multline*}
Second phrase in a paragraph.
```

Doing `pandoc my.md -o my.tex` yields:

```
\textbf{First} phrase in a paragraph.

\begin{multline*}
some long formulae
\end{multline*}

Second phrase in a paragraph.
```

Clearly this is inappropriate behavior due to extra vertical space put by latex in resulting PDF when it sees extra blank lines around `multline`.

Is there a way to suppress extra blank lines in .tex output of `pandoc`?

Comment: Pandoc converts this to a Raw Tex Block which is always a block level element. But you might use a [template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates) and set the vertical space before/after `multline`s in LaTeX.

Comment: @mb21 I think it would be incosistent to try fix pandoc translation problems with latex. But would you please be more specific on what do you mean by “this” in “Pandoc converts this to a Raw Tex Block”. Do you mean each begin/end pair?

Comment: `\begin{}...\end{}` is a [block](http://spec.commonmark.org#blocks-and-inlines) element.

Comment: @mb21 it's quite weird decision (if it really true): both $$/$$ and begin{multline}/end{multline} create displaystyle formula. Why the former considered inline while the latter processed as a block. Complete nonsense.

Comment: You can convince yourself with: `pandoc -t native my.md` or `pandoc -t json my.md` Notice the `RawBlock`? If I'm not mistaken, LaTeX's `\begin{}...\end{}`is always a paragraph-making environment as well?

Comment: @mb21 yes, thank's. Still it's very confusing decision. Seems like it's worth introducing an issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Proper vertical multline]

---

Modification:

```
**First** phrase in a paragraph.
\empty{
\begin{multline*}
some long formulae
\end{multline*}
}
Second phrase in a paragraph.
```

parses to

```
\textbf{First} phrase in a paragraph. \empty{
\begin{multline*}
some long formulae
\end{multline*}
} Second phrase in a paragraph.
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
**First** phrase in a paragraph. \begin{multline*}
some long formulae
\end{multline*} Second phrase in a paragraph.
```

`pandoc -t latex` with the above input and pandoc 2.2.1 gives:

```
\textbf{First} phrase in a paragraph. \begin{multline*}
some long formulae
\end{multline*} Second phrase in a paragraph.
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? For me, the result is just the same as with the initial example.

Comment: I have only pandoc 1.19 at hand, the one from the official Ubuntu 17.10 repo. For that one, the solution does not work. Good to know that it works in newer versions though.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases (and feel free to upvote the answer ;))